# passing array to flot

Tags: php, flot

I have been trying to make a graph plot with flot, and have ran into a problem.I Think the problem is with the way m using the php variable with flot  Aside from that the graph isn't showing so I must have done something wrong. Below is the graph code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>    
<head>    
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>Flot Examples</title>
   <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

//CONNECTING TO THE SERVER
   $servername = "XXX";
   $username = "YYY";
   $password = "ZZZ";
   conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

   $sql = "SELECT NAME, AGE FROM pro_db";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $wt=array();

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  //storing the values in the array
  $wt[]=$row;//is this the right way
  }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}

?>
  <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
//accessing the array
    var data = <?php echo $wt; ?>; 

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [data], {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.6,
            align: "center" }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "categories",
        tickLength: 0
    }
  });
 });
 </script>

</body>
</html>``
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's completely working example i made. If something doesn't work - there's some error with data. Try `var_dump` how your `$wt` array looks like in the end;

```
$data = [
    ['Andrew', 31],
    ['Helen', 29],
    ['Dasha', 24],
    ['Denis', 23]
];

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
    <script>
        var data = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
        $("#canvas").plot([data], {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.6,
                    align: "center"
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "categories",
                tickLength: 0
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there are no errors but its not displaying the graph

Comment: Another edit (it seems you still need `[`, `]` brackets around `data`, even if it's an array by itself.

Comment: the above example works when i use the data inside the body otherwise it doesnt what might be the problem? @Eternal1

Comment: Try `var_dump` how your `$wt` array looks like in the end;

Comment: if i use var_dump inside the loop its giving me some values ,but outside its giving null

Comment: inside the loop when i do echo $row['name].[$row['age'] m getting the proper data.i think m doing some mistake while storing it ..@Eternal1 please do help me with it.

Comment: the above example which u have given doesnt work for me ..what might be the problem?some problem with the set up?

Comment: Can you please edit your question with exact code you are using?

Comment: the above code is the one m trying to execute.......what m telling is like why is the example code u posted not working for me?is there some problem with my configuration settings or so..

Comment: Earlier you wrote that it works, and breaks only if you replace `$data` with your database query result. So, which one is true?

Comment: if i place the data inside the script it will work otherwise it doesnt

Comment: I need exact copy-paste from the code you are using. It could be a simple typo for all i know.